# Mouseleave event does not fire when element is being removed()

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a mouseleave event. Inside the div I have a child div with onclick event.
The parent mouseleave event hides itself, the child onclick removes itself from the parent.

When the child removes itself, the parent div contracts and the parent boundaries move outside of the mouse cursor location.

The problem is that when the boundaries move outside of the mouse cursor location, the expected mouseleave event does not get fired.

Comment: I've read it 3 times, still not sure what you're saying. Give us a fiddle demonstrating your issue perhaps...

Comment: This could easily be browser-dependent; you'd be better off checking the bounds against the cursor manually when you change its shape programmatically.

Comment: (Mouse enter/leave implies some movement from the mouse, whereas here, the object has effectively left the mouse!)

Comment: example of the issue: http://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/PpeLZX?editors=1010